# minidump error when importing dxf, causing QGIS to crash

Tags: qgis, dxf, minidump

QGIS (2.18) crashes when I use dxf importer to import a simple dxf file (Autodesk 2000 dxf format).

May I ask how to solve this problem?

error message:

> minidump written to
>   C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-20170214-140259-18376-13556-0332f5a.dmp

[image]

Comment: Please provide all errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.  Here are some previous Q&As that you may wish to review for debugging hints: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bqgis%5D+minidump+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Thanks, PolyGeo! However, I'm not able to find a post in the list you suggested that is related to this type of error caused by importing DXF file... Is it related to the dxf file format to be used?

Comment: I did not say that there was a duplicate there.  I just said that reviewing them might give you some ideas for how to approach minidumps.

Comment: As of version 2.18.2, there is a new DXF / DWG interface.
For the version 2.18. I recommend you the plugin "Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter"

Comment: Can you provide a test dataset? Otherwise we cannot try to reproduce the issue.